# TableViewCell: vertical line in right place next to checkmark on iPhone 6(s)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with basic cell. 
On selection, the cell is marked with checkmark accessory.

[image: storyboard]

On iPhone 6S random cells have a vertical line to left of the accessory when it exists. On other devices it isn't seen.

[image: iPhone 6s]

Some ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Try cell style custom maybe

Comment: clear color all subviews background in cell

Comment: Custom cell resolved this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the style of cell basic to custom.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue before and this was my solution.

If you do have a subview in your cell, which has a non-integer width, this can cause vertical lines to appear.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Use only basic cell without anything else. So, haven't subviews.